# Pagination PHP addressbook

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am building an table with all of the users in the domain. I got the table working and I put a little code for my Pagination in it but now I keep getting errors...

```
//connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Aantal per page
$num_rec_per_page=30;
//check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 


$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, department FROM tl_member ORDER BY lastname ASC LIMIT                   30";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<table><tr><br><hr><th align='left'>Naam</th><th align='center'>telefoon</th><th       align='right' >afdeling</th></tr>";
// output data in rows
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<tr><td align='left'>" .$row["firstname"].", " .$row["lastname"]."</td><td   align='center'>". $row["phone"]."</td><td align='right'>". $row["department"]."</td></tr>";
 }               
echo "</table>";
    } else {
echo "0 results";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tl_member";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($sql); //run the query
$total_records = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=-1'>".'|<'."</a> "; // Goto 1st page  

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
echo "<a href='pagination.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> "; // Goto last page 
$conn->close();
?>
```

The errors I get is :

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\pagination.php on line 56

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\pagination.php on line 57

I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

The first argument should be the mysqli resourcelink, the second the query;

```
$rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //run the query
```

Comment: I do not fully understand the first query can you explain ? // The second query works after implementing but then I see all the 30 pages when I select them It gives no data it just stays on the same page